# MongoDB and Batch script operation

Tags: mongodb, shell, batch-file

I am trying to run MongoDB queries from batch script in windows...
I can not find any reference how to do that. Please can you show me some sample commands and one more question.

I am running this command for changing the database...

```
mongo --eval "use Sample_Test"
```

It does not work.

when I am inserting some data. It works, but, inserts in the default database, test.

```
mongo --eval "db.restaurants.insert({'Name':'Vishal'})"
```

I want to insert data in Sample_Test Database.

I only know above `"mongo --eval"` command, if anybody knows some more, please share it.....it would really help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is getting inserted to default database as your `use DB` is not working here.
You need to add database name here using `-d` if you are using older version of MongoDB like following :

```
mongo -d Sample_Test --eval  "db.restaurants.insert({'Name':'Vishal'})"
```

or you can execute any script file which contains all your mongo script like following:

```
mongo -d Sample_Test --eval mongoScript.js
```

> In Mongo version 3.2, `-d` flag is not needed. For more information about script refer [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/)

So you can simply use

```
mongo Sample_Test --eval "db.restaurants.insert({'Name':'Vishal'})"
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: With mongo version 4 you do not include the --eval when running a script file : mongo localhost:27017/test myjsfile.js

Answer (score 0):

use this code on place of your code:

```
mongo.exe Sample_Test --eval  "db.restaurants.insert({'Name':'Vishal'})"
```

but if you want to run multiple commands in one session login use script file.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the URL style to connect to a MongoDb server and database like:

```
mongo "mongoldb://localhost:8000/myCars" --eval "db.getCollection('restaurants').insert({'Name':'Vishal'})
```

You can also put credentials into the URL.

See: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/